# TYPO3 v12.4 500 Page Not Found - The page did not exist or was inaccessible. Reason: No TypoScript record found

Tags: typo3, typoscript2

I'm learning the newest typo3 CMS. I installed it through docker, and in the php container I installed the typo3 cms with that code: `composer create-project typo3/cms-base-distribution:^12 example-project-directory`. I logged in in the backend like mywebsite.localhost/typo3. I created a new page, added some content like "regular text element", but when I open it in the browser, I get the 500 error "500 Page Not Found  - The page did not exist or was inaccessible. Reason: No TypoScript record found!"
What should I do to get rid of this error? Sadly there is no tutorial about the v12.4 verison, all the content is outdated on youtube, also I didn't find any straight answer in the documentation.

Comment: TypoScript is one of the basic concepts behind TYPO3. Most tutorials will help you, even if they cover a older version (like v10/v11).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-typoscript-in-45-minutes/main/en-us/TypoScriptOverview/TheTermTemplate/Index.html

If you read this document, you will get an idea of how you can resolve this.

The following TypoScript setup code is enough to remove this warning:

```
# Default PAGE object:
page = PAGE
page.10  < styles.content.get
```